# How to abstract from data type parameters in class instances?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

As a toy project, I would like to understand how to model mathematical groups in Haskell in general.

To start us off, we begin by observing that a to be defined `Group` is just a `Monoid` with inversion.

```
class (Monoid m) => Group m where
    minvert :: m -> m
```

Next, we first restrict ourselves to cyclic groups and start by defining the cyclic group of order 12.

```
data Cyclic12 = Cyclic12 Int deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Finally, we instantiate both classes for `Cyclic12`.

```
instance Monoid Cyclic12 where
    mempty = Cyclic12 0
    mappend (Cyclic12 x) (Cyclic12 y) = Cyclic12 ((x + y) `mod` 12)

instance Group Cyclic12 where
    minvert (Cyclic12 x) = Cyclic12 ((0 - x) `mod` 12)
```

How do I abstract the previous definition from the specific value of 12 to allow a more generic definition of different cyclic groups?

Ideally, I would like to write definitions like

```
instance Monoid (Cyclic k) where
    mempty = Cyclic k 0
    mappend (Cyclic k x) (Cyclic k y) = Cyclic k ((x + y) `mod` k)

instance Group (Cyclic k) where
    minvert (Cyclic k x) = Cyclic k ((0 - x) `mod` k)
```

But with a data definition like

```
data Cyclic = Cyclic Int Int deriving (Show, Eq)
```

we still don't get very far, because `k` is "not in scope". Regarding its apparent triviality I have a feeling to be missing out on some fundamental concept here. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You may be interested in `DataKinds` and `GHC.TypeLits`, which permit natural numbers at the type level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must make the order of the cyclic group part of the type. One way of doing this is to use [the builtin type level natural numbers GHC gives us](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))

data Cyclic (n :: Nat) = Cyclic Integer deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Which lets us make the two instances pretty easily:

```
instance KnownNat n => Monoid (Cyclic n) where
    mempty = Cyclic 0
    Cyclic x `mappend` Cyclic y = Cyclic $ (x + y) `mod` natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)

instance KnownNat n => Group (Cyclic n) where
    minvert (Cyclic x) = Cyclic $ negate x `mod` natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

The `KnownNat` part of the signature basically says that whatever `n :: Nat` ends up being, it is something whose value we should be able to extract using `natVal`.

Then, once loaded in GHCi:

```
ghci> :set -XDataKinds
ghci> type Z12 = Cyclic 12
ghci> mappend (Cyclic 8 :: Z12) (Cyclic 7 :: Z12)
Cyclic 3
ghci> minvert (Cyclic 4 :: Z12)
Cyclic 8
```

#### Aside on extensions

- `DataKinds` lets us have a type parameter `n` which isn't a type. We say that its *kind* is not type (`*`). In this case, `n` has kind `Nat` (`n :: Nat`).
- `KindSignatures` just lets us write `n :: Nat` where `::` means "has kind" (instead of "has type") when it makes sense.
- `ScopedTypeVariables` makes it so that the `n` type variable in `Proxy :: Proxy n` is the same one as in the instance head `instance KnownNat m => Monoid (Cyclic n) where`.